# Postgres function creation - ERROR: no language specified SQL state: 42P13

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers

I am new to functions. I am trying to create a function by following this link - `http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/creating-first-trigger-postgresql/`. But it gives some error. The code block and the error is given below.

Code block:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_last_name_changes()
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
 IF NEW.last_name <> OLD.last_name THEN
 INSERT INTO employee_audits(employee_id,last_name,changed_on)
 VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name,now());
 END IF;
 
 RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$
```

And the error:

> ERROR: no language specified
> SQL state: 42P13

What can I try next?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION log_last_name_changes()
RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
IF NEW.last_name <> OLD.last_name THEN
INSERT INTO employee_audits(employee_id,last_name,changed_on)
VALUES(OLD.id,OLD.last_name,now());
END IF;

RETURN NEW;
END;
$BODY$

LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE -- Says the function is implemented in the plpgsql language; VOLATILE says the function has side effects.
COST 100; -- Estimated execution cost of the function.
```

Comment: this creates the trigger. thanks a lot. Can you please explain what is the meaning of LANGUAGE & COST

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/sql-createfunction.html  Read the documentation for pgsql create function. They have explained it clearly.

Comment: This may be a good answer to the original question, but I can't really use it as a random googler coming to this question. What is it exactly that makes this work? A link to the docs is not a good way to avoid explaining things on your answer

Comment: Particularly `COST`, the docs say something about it but the vast majority of people looking at this do not have a deep enough SQL background to understand why that number should be 100.

Comment: `COST` here refers to the estimated execution cost of the function in the units of [cpu_operator_cost](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/runtime-config-query.html#GUC-CPU-OPERATOR-COST. That is, the cost of processing each operator or function executed during a query. The default is 0.0025

Answer (score 0):

If arriving here because your `function` gave you the same error (like mine did).. here's an over-baked example of using a function to update the tweet on the bottom right "blurb" with "hello world".

**Important note: language goes BEFORE the last semicolon (see below). This is easy to miss in the accepted solution.**

| id (serial) | pub_id (text) | tweet (text) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc | hello world |
| 2 | def | blurb |

```
-- Optional drop if replace fails below.
drop function if exists sync_tweets(text, text);

create or replace function sync_tweets(
    src_pub_id text, -- function arguments
    dst_pub_id text
) returns setof tweets as -- i.e. rows. int, text work too
$$
declare
    src_id    int; -- temp function variables (not args)
    dest_id   int;
    src_tweet text;
begin
    -- query result into a temp variable
    src_id := (select id from tweets where pub_id = src_pub_id);

    -- query result into a temp variable (another way)
    select tweet into src_tweet from tweets where id = src_id;

    dest_id := (select id from tweets where pub_id = dst_pub_id);
    update tweets set tweet=src_tweet where id = dest_id;

    return query -- i.e. rows, return 0 with return int above works too
        select * from tweets where pub_id in (src_pub_id, dst_pub_id);
end
$$ language plpgsql; -- need the language to avoid ERROR 42P13

-- Run it!
select * from sync_tweets('abc', 'def');

/*
  Outputs
   __________________________________________________ 
  |  id (serial)  |  pub_id (text)  |  tweet (text)  |
  |---------------|-----------------|----------------|
  |  1            |  abc            |  hello world   |
  |  2            |  def            |  blurb         |
  --------------------------------------------------
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error below:

> ERROR:  no language specified

When I created the [PL/pgSQL function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html) as shown below:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN 2;
END;
$$;
```

So, I set `LANGUAGE plpgsql` as shown below, then the error was solved:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
RETURN 2;
END; -- ↓ Here ↓
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Or:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION my_func() RETURNS INTEGER LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
BEGIN                                    -- ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑
RETURN 2;
END;
$$;
```